# Как ограничить количество кликов в указанное время?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

```
 function SelForce(fid) {
   cur_fid = fid;
       $(".force_icon").removeClass("cur_force_icon");
       $("#for_" + fid).addClass("cur_force_icon");
       $("#force_name").html(Lang('for', fid));
       $("#force_desc").html(Lang('ford', fid));
  var val = GetPriceForce(fid);
    $("#force_price").html(val + ' ' + Arif(val, t(-1)) + ' ' + t(63));
    $("#force_but").html('<a onClick="ex(\'UseForce\', {fid:' + fid + '}); return false;" class="button">
    <span class="button-cont"><span class="button-side">' + t(62) + '</span></span></a>');
}
```

Помогите ограничить количество кликов. Данная функция в игре использует важную силу и при двойном клике тратится лишняя сила, что очень напрягает игроков. Как прописать ограничение на количество кликов раз в 5 секунд для onClick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самое просто решение использовать `setTimeout` и сделать некую проверку, вот пример кода:

```js
var time = 5000;
var fightBtn = $('#fight');
var fightCheck = true;

fightBtn.click(function() {
  if (fightCheck == true) {
    console.log('Удар');
    fightCheck = false;
    timeOut();
  } else {
    console.log('У вас не накопилась энергия для удара');
  }

});

function timeOut() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    fightCheck = true;
    console.log('Удар готов!')
  }, time)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="fight">fight</button>
```

Comment: Не сказал бы, что это ***самое*** простое решение.

Answer (score 1):

Простое решение "в лоб" - в обработчике "применения силы" проверяйте, чтобы последний вызов был ранее 5 сек назад, иначе ничего не делайте. Код типа:

```
if (current_time >= last_time + 5 sec) {
  do_something();
  last_time = current_time;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно создать таймер, который будет обнулять количество кликов каждые N секунд.
Получится, что-то типа такого:

```
let count=0;
obj.onclick= function(){
    count++;
    if (count>разрешенное_количество_кликов) return;
    /*Делаем что-то по нажатию*/
};
setInterval(()=>{count=0;},5000);
```

Comment: Верно ли по вашему предложению, обнуление будет происходить каждые 5сек, например в 40, 45, 50 сек, и что подгадав время, я смогу кликнуть и вызвать что-то два раза - в 49.9 и в 50.1 секунду? (т.е. почти подряд)

Comment: Да, в данном случае так можно сделать " я смогу кликнуть и вызвать что-то два раза - 49.9 и в 50.1 секунду". Тогда предлагаю решение чуть лучше:
let count=0;
obj.onclick= function(){
    count++;
    if (count>разрешенное_количество_кликов) return;
    setTimeout(()=>{if (count>0) count--},5000); /* т.е. клик обнулиться через 5 секунд */
    /*Делаем что-то по нажатию*/
};

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Signal {
  constructor() {
    this.handlers = new Set();
  }

  on(handler) {
    this.handlers.add(handler);
  }
  off(handler) {
    this.handlers.delete(handler);
  }
  dispatch(event) {
    this.handlers.forEach(handler => handler(event));
  }

}
class Toggle {
  constructor(isToggle = false) {
    this.isToggle = isToggle;
  }
  toggle() {
    this.isToggle = !this.isToggle;
  }
}

const ClickerWIthTimeoutEvent = {
  COUNT: 'count',
  DONE: 'done'
};

class ClickerWIthTimeout {
  constructor(timeout = 0, startCount = 0, endCount = 0, id = 'clicker') {
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.startCount = startCount;
    this.endCount = endCount;
    this.id = id;

    this.countSignal = new Signal();
    this.doneSignal = new Signal();
    this.toggle = new Toggle(true);

    this.count = this.startCount;
  }



  click() {
    if (this.toggle.isToggle) {
      this.toggle.toggle();
      this.count++;

      this.countSignal.dispatch({
        target: this,
      });

      let isDoneValid = this.endCount !== 0 && this.count === this.endCount;


      if (isDoneValid) {
        this.doneSignal.dispatch({
          target: this
        });
      }

      if (!isDoneValid) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.toggle.toggle();
        }, this.timeout);
      }
    }
  }
}

const countHandler = ({
  target
}) => {
  console.log(`[count signal] id: ${target.id}, count: ${target.count}`);
};
const doneHandler = ({
  target
}) => {
  console.log(`[done signal] id: ${target.id}, count: ${target.count}`);

  clickerWithTimeOut.countSignal.off(countHandler);
  clickerWithTimeOut.doneSignal.off(doneHandler);
};

let clickerWithTimeOut = new ClickerWIthTimeout(1000, 0, 3, 'SomeClicker');
clickerWithTimeOut.countSignal.on(countHandler);
clickerWithTimeOut.doneSignal.on(doneHandler);

document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clickerWithTimeOut.click();
});
```